# Faster way to compute difference between two csv files

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to compute difference between two large csv files (~ 4GB) to obtain newly added rows and writing these into an output csv file. I'm able to obtain this functionality for relatively small files (~50MB) by using the following code.

```
input_file1 = "data.csv"
input_file2 = "data_1.csv"
output_path = "out.csv"

with open(input_file1, 'r') as t1, open(input_file2, 'r') as t2:
    fileone = t1.readlines()
    filetwo = t2.readlines()

with open(output_path, 'w') as outFile:
    for line in filetwo:
        if line not in fileone:
            outFile.write(line)
```

However, for larger files, the above code is either too slow (runs for about half an hour) or crashes with lack of memory space.

Is there a faster way to obtain the difference for large csv files?

Comment: Maybe dump the data into a database and dedupe? 4 GB is a huge file for this kind of very processing-heavy task. At least in a DB the engine should be able to handle the memory management somewhat gracefully...

Comment: Try reading through this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44447107/fastest-way-to-compare-two-huge-csv-files-in-pythonnumpy?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @Sneha, does the second CSV file always have the new data added to the base of the file? Or is it sorted into the data in a different way?

Comment: If the .csv files are both sorted, you could work with a merge-sort like collator. This has complexity O(N+M), where your double-loop thing is O(N*M) Plus: it needs to store only one M + one N record in memory.

Comment: @Grant - the second csv file will have the new data added to the base of the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to read the second file fully, just read line by line.

And for the speed, just make a `set` out of the first file (fast lookup, and saves memory if there are duplicate lines). For this you have to keep the second file open when you're writing the result:

```
input_file1 = "data.csv"
input_file2 = "data_1.csv"
output_path = "out.csv"

with open(input_file1, 'r') as t1:
    fileone = set(t1)

with open(input_file2, 'r') as t2, open(output_path, 'w') as outFile:
    for line in t2:
        if line not in fileone:
            outFile.write(line)
```

- `for line in t2` reads the file line by line (always avoid `readlines()` if you can) so even if the file is big, the memory footprint is small.
- `fileone` takes some memory, true, but hopefully if it's smaller and/or has duplicate lines, not so much, and of course less than with `readlines()`
- `if line not in fileone` may look the same as before, but it has an average  `O(1)` complexity, which makes the program much faster

Answer (score 2):

You could use Data base or alternatively a **Sort Merge**. I will give you the basic algorithm   (rather than python Code)

#### Sort merge Description

The idea is to sort the 2 files into the same order. Then read sequentially through the 2 files

- if records in the 2 files are equal --> in both files
- if old-file-record > new-file-record   --> record has been **inserted**
- if old-file-record < new-file-record   --> record has been **deleted**

#### Sort merge Algorithm

```
Sort the 2 files to new SortedFiles using the Operating Systems sort 
(use the whole record as sort key)

Open/Read  SortedOldFile
Open/Read  SortedNewFile

while (not end-of-file-SortedOldFile) and (not end-of-file-SortedOldFile):
    if SortedOldFile.record < SortedNewFile.record:
       ## Deleted processing goes here
       read SortedOldFile
    elseif SortedOldFile.record > SortedNewFile.record:
       ## Insert processing  goes here
       read SortedNewFile
    else
       read SortedOldFile
       read SortedNewFile

while (not end-of-file-SortedOldFile):
   ## Deleted processing
   read SortedOldFile

while (not end-of-file-SortedNewFile):
   ## Insert processing
   read SortedNewFile
```

Advantages:

- uses minimal memory
- it scales to absolutely massive files
- Should be quick enough, Operating System Sorts are very efficient

Disadvantages:

- Uses extra disk space (disk space is cheap these days)
- code is Operating System dependent

Answer (score 0):

you can hash the line to compress the smaller set, then compare. 
or using more advanced algorithm to find finger print

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_(computing)](http://fingerprint)

```
import hashlib
input_file1 = "data.csv"
input_file2 = "data_1.csv"
output_path = "out.csv"

def get_data(file_):
    res = {}
    m = hashlib.md5()
    for i, line in file_:
      hashed_line = m.update(line).hexdigest()
      if hashed_line not in res:
        res[hashed_line ] = []
      res[hashed_line ].append(i)


with open(input_file1, 'r') as t1, open(input_file2, 'r') as t2:
    file1_data =  get_data(t1)
    file2_data =  get_data(t2)
    file2_raw = t2.readlines()


with open(output_path, 'w') as outFile:
    for line in file2_data:
        if line not in file1_data:
            outFile.write(file2_raw[file2_data[line]])
```

Comment: oops `for line in file2_data:
        if line not in file2_data:` again :) time to test your code :) I would be cautious with hashes. Even md5 isn't bijective. if hashes don't match, then okay, it's different, but I think you have to test values if hashes match...

Comment: the hashing thing is interesting, but it doesn't save memory, since you still need the original data to write back the file. Besides if hashes match, you still have to compare the actual string values. So it's not sure that you gain time.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it is not comparing string. it compare hashed string in dict, so it is O(1) speed. for memory usage, it should smaller than op's

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre hashed string in dict should smaller than string hash(set) in memory

Comment: yes, but my point is you can have `md5.hexdigest(s1) == md5.hexdigest(s2)` with `s1 != s2`. Unlikely, but possible.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre agree, it lost some accentuate

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a method to handle this. I will try and let you know if such large files could be handled.