# Interesting ways to check the size of an int

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to see whether a number is 8, 16, 32, or 64 bytes (anything over 64 bits I count as 64 bits). Here is what I currently am doing:

```
8 if not val>>8 else 16 if not val>>16 else 32 if not val>>32 else 64
```

What are some other ways that are commonly used to check bitsize?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329794/get-size-of-integer-in-python

Comment: @ikegami No.  Use `num.bit_length()`.  There's no need to resort to floating point.  Example:  `(123).bit_length()` is `7`.

Comment: @Tom Karzes. Cool, though that returns a number of bits, not octets. So something like `ceil( num.bit_length() / 8 )` (Not Python, but you get the idea)

Comment: @ikegami Yes, the result would need to be converted to what OP is looking for, but that provides the raw data.

Comment: On the plus side, since 1/8 is a power of two (2^(-3)), there's no floating point error to worry about.

Comment: @TomKarzes yes of course I can use something like that but that's not really the point of the question. Anyways, ok it's marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @David542 I wasn't answering your question, I was responding to a comment that's since been deleted.

Comment: @David542 There is a way to do what you want without any conditional expressions, but it will be more convoluted and slower than what you're already doing.

Comment: @David542 Here's an expression that should give the same results, at least for positive numbers, but it's worse than what you have:  `min(64, 8 << ((((n|1).bit_length() + 7) >> 3) - 1).bit_length())`

Comment: @TomKarzes wow that's pretty neat. How did you come up with that expression? Actually, the whole point of this question was for people to post answers like yours right there, with how it works! But anyways, someone probably took 5 seconds to read the title of the question, searched "bit length in python" and then took all of ten seconds to mark duplicate :(

Comment: @David542 It starts with the number of needed bits, but in order to force 0 to require a bit, it uses `(n|1)` which only affects that case.  Then to get the number of bytes, it divides by 8, rounding up (i.e. add 7 and right shift by 3).  Then we want to force it to a power of two, so we again want the number of bits (after subtracting 1) and then raise two to that power, then multiply by 8, which can be accomplished by left-shifting 8 by that amount.  Then, to cap it at 64, we take the min with 64.